# Adding colormap legend to Folium map

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial, colormap, folium

I'm trying to make a map in Folium with multiple layers, each consisting of shaded areas (using GeoJSON) with colors given by a colormap. I'd like to add legends to my layers. I found a first solution [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/528), but the problem with this solution were that the legend is fixed at the top right and more importantly, that it's always there. Instead, I'd like a legend that is only shown when the corresponding layer is shown.

Here is some example code that I tried (where m is my Folium map and cm1 and cm2 are color maps):

```
folium.GeoJson(data['Temp'],
    name='Temp',
    style_function=lambda x: {
            'fillColor': cm1(x['properties']['Temp']),
            'fillOpacity': 0.2,
            'color' : None
                            },
    highlight_function=lambda x: {'weight':3, 'color':'black'},
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['Temp', 'Rain'],
                                            labels=True,
                                            sticky=True
                                            ), show=False).add_to(m)

folium.GeoJson(data['Rain'],
    name='Rain',
    style_function=lambda x: {
            'fillColor': cm2(x['properties']['Rain']),
            'fillOpacity': 0.2,
            'color' : None
                            },
    highlight_function=lambda x: {'weight':3, 'color':'black'},
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['Temp', 'Rain'],
                                            labels=True,
                                            sticky=True
                                            ), show=False).add_to(m)

cm1.caption = 'Temp scale'
cm2.caption = 'Rain scale'
m.add_child(cm1)
m.add_child(cm2)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

How can I change my code so that the legends are only shown when the corresponding layers are shown? (And if possible, how can I move the legends to the bottom left?)

Comment: Look at [this link](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/BibMartin/f153aa957ddc5fadc64929abdee9ff2e) to see how you can control which colormaps are displayed when viewing each layer

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the position of the LayerControl:

```
folium.map.LayerControl('topleft', collapsed=False).add_to(m)
```

if you know a bit of JavaScript you can change/manipulate e.g.:
[legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466683/create-a-legend-on-a-folium-map/58077924#58077924)

Answer (score 0):

The [commented link](https://nbviewer.org/gist/BibMartin/f153aa957ddc5fadc64929abdee9ff2e) gets most of the way to the solution! It just needs modification of the `overlayadd` and `overlayremove` events to `layeradd` and `layerremove`, so that the solution also works when you're using mutually-exclusive (overlay = False) layers.

```python
# Adapted from: https://nbviewer.org/gist/BibMartin/f153aa957ddc5fadc64929abdee9ff2e
from branca.element import MacroElement
from jinja2 import Template

class BindColormap(MacroElement):
    """Binds a colormap to a given layer.

    Parameters
    ----------
    colormap : branca.colormap.ColorMap
        The colormap to bind.
    """
    def __init__(self, layer, colormap):
        super(BindColormap, self).__init__()
        self.layer = layer
        self.colormap = colormap
        self._template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            {{this.colormap.get_name()}}.svg[0][0].style.display = 'block';
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('layeradd', function (eventLayer) {
                if (eventLayer.layer == {{this.layer.get_name()}}) {
                    {{this.colormap.get_name()}}.svg[0][0].style.display = 'block';
                }});
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('layerremove', function (eventLayer) {
                if (eventLayer.layer == {{this.layer.get_name()}}) {
                    {{this.colormap.get_name()}}.svg[0][0].style.display = 'none';
                }});
        {% endmacro %}
        """)  # noqa

# set up base map
map = folium.Map(tiles=None)
layer0 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='Base Map',overlay=True,control=False)
folium.TileLayer(tiles='OpenStreetMap').add_to(layer0)
layer0.add_to(map)

# imagine you've already defined two layers and associated colorbars
# call them layer1, colorbar1; layer2, colorbar2
map.add_child(colorbar1)
map.add_child(BindColormap(layer1,colorbar1))
map.add_child(colorbar2)
map.add_child(BindColormap(layer2,colorbar2))

folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(test_map)
```