# Folium, make legend disappear when switching layer (LayerControl)

Tags: python, folium

I created some legends using the html example by InLaw(1) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466683/create-a-legend-on-a-folium-map) answer. From that answer, I also manage to get [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/talbertc-usgs/18f8901fc98f109f2b71156cf3ac81cd) legend using a MacroElement from Branca (2), where template is an html macro template. What I want is that (any) those legends appear and disappear from the map in accordance to a LayerControl.

```
(1) map.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element( legend_html ))
```

```
(2) macro = MacroElement()
macro._template = Template(template)
m.get_root().add_child(macro)
```

What have I tried? I tried adding the html and MacroElement to the FeatureLayer or a Choropleth map with no avail. After lurking for a while in the web I found [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/BibMartin/f153aa957ddc5fadc64929abdee9ff2e) example that uses java script (I guess, I have -0 experience with JS) to make the bar invisible. But, when I substituted the LinearColormap for any of the above, the legend did not disappear. For example, using the variable `macro` from (2) I tried this:

```
m.add_child(BindColormap(FeatureGroup, macro))
m.add_child(BindColormap(Choropleth, macro))
```

Where `FeatureGroup` and `Choropleth` are the names of the variables named like that for simplicity for this example.

I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I would like to do something similar for a map that I'm making.

Comment: @Will Hi, I'm sorry, At that point in time I couldn't figured it out but I change to R and worked like a charm. I don't know if they have changed anything in these years.