# I want to add a legend in folium map to the code below

Tags: geopandas, folium

```
m = folium.Map(location=[39.735,-84.15],zoom_start=10.5)
for idx, row in gdf1.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']], popup=row['Name'], 
icon=folium.Icon(color=row['Colors'])).add_to(m)
```

This code shows the following output

[image]

I want to make a legend that will say the blue marker represent 'other hospitals' and the red marker represent 'dayton'

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here in this related post
[Create a Legend on a Folium map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466683/create-a-legend-on-a-folium-map)

There are two possibilities mentioned:

- using layercontrol with colors (would mean you use multiple MarkerCluster)
- just adding an image as an overlay with your text and color